# Primefaces autocorrect option in selenium

Tags: sql, selenium

Tried to select autocomplete textbox , i'm getting an exception.

```
WebElement autoOptions = driver.findElement(By.id("form:mat_input"));
autoOptions.sendKeys("b");
```

html snap :-[image: snap]

```
<p:autoComplete id="mat" required="true"
value="#{vCreateSupplyRequest._RequestMaterial}"
completeMethod="#{vCreateSupplyRequest.getMaterials}"
var="item" itemLabel="#{item.materialName}" itemValue="#{item}"
converter="materialConverter" forceSelection="true">
<p:ajax event="itemSelect"
listener="#{vCreateSupplyRequest.onMaterialSelection}"
update="mainGrid,mainGrid1" />
<p:column headerText="Material">
<h:outputText value="#{item.materialName}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Category">
<h:outputText value="#{item.materialCategory.categoryName}" />
</p:column>
</p:autoComplete>
```

Comment: i tried it ..but im not getting it ...

Comment: List<WebElement> optionsToSelect = autoOptions
    .findElements(By
      .className("ui-autocomplete-item ui-autocomplete-row ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-state-highlight"));
  for (WebElement option : optionsToSelect) {
   if (option.getText().equals(textToSelect)) {
    System.out.println("Trying to select: " + textToSelect);
    option.click();
    break;
   }
  }

Comment: Do you mean you want to click on an option from automcomplete suggestion list?? and what is the exception you are getting?? and alson share relevant HTML code here instead of screenshot..:)

Comment: @SaurabhGaur yes i want to click on an option from suggestion list..

Comment: Then you need to share relevant  HTML code if you want a solution instead of screenshot..:)

Comment: `<p:autoComplete id="mat" required="true" value="#{vCreateSupplyRequest._RequestMaterial}"
completeMethod="#{vCreateSupplyRequest.getMaterials}"
var="item" itemLabel="#{item.materialName}" itemValue="#{item}"
converter="materialConverter" forceSelection="true">
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{vCreateSupplyRequest.onMaterialSelection}"
update="mainGrid,mainGrid1" />
<p:column headerText="Material">
<h:outputText value="#{item.materialName}" />
</p:column>
<p:column headerText="Category">
<h:outputText value="#{item.materialCategory.categoryName}" /></p:column></p:autoComplete>`

Comment: @SaurabhGaur html code!!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide it into your question instead of comments..:)

Comment: yeah i edited!!can any one find me a solution for this?

Comment: So in your HTML which element do you want to select? and why did you remove the screenshot, please add it as well

Comment: i want to select the 2 element!1

Comment: @SaurabhGaur snap is posted ...

Comment: @BalusC  can you plz help me in selecting autocorrect option